# Bug occuring in flutter tagging

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter tagging for an instantly searchable text field, but on Android, whenever I try typing something in it, the keyboard disappears immediately. I'm sure this issue is related to state but I can't figure out how to fix it. This is the flutter tagging code:

```
FlutterTagging<Category>(
            enableImmediateSuggestion: true,
            initialItems: _selectedCategories,
            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                icon: Icon(Icons.category),
                hintText: 'clothing',
                labelText: 'Select categories',
              ),
            ),
            // findSuggestions: Future.value(store.categories.values.toList()),
            findSuggestions: store.searchCategories,
            configureSuggestion: (Category cat) {
              return SuggestionConfiguration(title: Text(cat.name));
            },
            configureChip: (Category cat) {
              return ChipConfiguration(
                label: Text(cat.name),
                backgroundColor: AppTheme.buildLightTheme().primaryColor,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                deleteIconColor: Colors.white,
              );
            },
            onChanged: () {
              if (_selectedCategories.length > 0) {
                setState(() {
                  _isCategorySelected = true;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  _isCategorySelected = false;
                });
              }
            },
          );
```